# Efficient way to read .yml file with different keys/filenodes

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I have a yaml file with following format:

```
%YAML:1.0

data1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 50
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 7.1709999084472656e+01, ...

data2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 50
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 7.1709999084472656e+01, ...

dataN: ...
```

I read the file content and save different data in different Mats:

```
QString nodeName[m_NameList.count()]= "data";
QString fullName[m_NameList.count()];
Mat inMat[m_NameList.count()];

for(int i= 0; i< m_NameList.count(); ++i)
{
    fullName[i]= nodeName[i].append(QString::number(i+1));

    FileStorage fsIn("file.yml", CV_STORAGE_READ);
    fsIn[fullName[i].toStdString()] >> inMat[i];
}
```

My problem is defining the node name `= "data";` if I want to give it to the `FileStorage`. Is there any other way that the `FileStorage` recognize the file-nodes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution myself, to read my node names from yaml file automatically, if another persons are interested. Basically I iterate the node names over `QStringList::iterator` and write them in `FileNode` and get them with `fileNode.name()` function.

```
int idx= 0;
FileStorage fs("file.yml", CV_STORAGE_READ);
FileNode fileNode;
Mat inMat[m_NameList.count()];

for(QStringList::iterator it= m_NameList.begin(); it!= m_NameList.end(); ++it)
{
  fileNode= fs[(*it).toStdString()];

  string key= fileNode.name();
  fs[key] >> inMat[idx];
  cout<<"Key Name: " << key << " Mat: " << inMat[idx]<<endl;
}
```